# How do I fetch and return a static geojson?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, geojson

I am trying to access a raw geojson via a fetch call and store it in state. This is just temporary not a production scale application. I'm unsure where i am going wrong though. My code is below:

```
 fetchData = async () => {
      let data = await
        fetch(
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson"
          )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((geojson) => {
            console.log("my_data: ", geojson)
            return geojson
          })

      console.log("my_data: ", geojson)
      this.setState({ geojson: data })
      return data
  }
```

I get the following:

```
my_data:  {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array(22), crs: {…}}
App.js:218 my_data:  /static/media/hh_2020112300_2020120623_Saturday_02.d9141b26.geojson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that `geojson` is out of scope when `console.log("my_data: ", geojson)` (the second one) executes. Shouldn't that second console log be `console.log("data: ", data)`?

Comment: I feel so dumb, thank you. I will upvote once I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let data = await fetch(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson",
  {
    headers: {
      accept:
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,bn;q=0.7",
      "cache-control": "max-age=0",
      "if-none-match":
        'W/"8c50b5f19d835c2097cf05ef5967bdf5531f37aaaed918b17479328f69aa7309"',
      "sec-ch-ua":
        '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-site": "none",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    },
    referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    body: null,
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "omit",
  }
);
```